# Lutris Error on Ubuntu 19.04 & Doesn't Launch

Tags: ubuntu, gaming

I have Python installed and WineHQ stable as well - which is required for [Lutris](http://lutris.net/).

I'm getting the following error when I just type in "lutris" in the terminal. And, when I try to click on the app icon by searching for it- nothing happens.

Could you explain what the error means? Can I fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe7aV.png

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's wanting an explicit locale to be set. Perhaps something like the following in the terminal:

```
export LC_ALL=C
lutris
```